# Fatal error: Function name must be a string with Anonymous function

Tags: php, fatal-error, anonymous-function

I am finding myself in a bit of a problem.
I have two anonymous functions and one calls the other. 
But when the function `$fCompleteDate` is called within the function `$fFindAndCreateDate`

I get the fatal error of:

> Function name must be a string.

The function `$fFindAndCreateDate` is called later on in the script.

I have literally no idea what the problem is.

```
$fCompleteDate = function($sDate)
{
  $sDate = str_replace('/', '-', $sDate);
  return str_repeat('01-', max(0, 2 - substr_count($sDate, '-'))) . $sDate;
};

$fFindAndCreateDate = function($aStruct)
{
  $aDateStructNames = array('', 'Remark', 'Formatted', 'Extra');
  foreach($aDateStructNames as $sDateStructName)
  {
    echo $fCompleteDate('2001');
    echo  'a : '. $fCompleteDate($aStruct['startDate'.$sDateStructName]);
    echo  'b : '. $fCompleteDate($aStruct['endDate'.$sDateStructName]);
  }
};
```

Comment: This is not valid PHP function. JS function and PHP function both are different.

Comment: I dont know why PHP called this way as Anonymous while nothing is anonymous in this kind of declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you use Anonymous functions so I updated my answer.

You need to specify that the second function use the first one like this:

```
$fFindAndCreateDate = function($aStruct) use ($fCompleteDate) {
 ....
}
```

Comment: Why is the function `$fFindAndCreateDate` called correctly then?

Comment: @KevinKamer Sorry for that, I updated my answer for  Anonymous functions. You only need to add  `use ($fCompleteDate)` to second function.